# UITableViewCell changing UITableView's datasource

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

This will be really useful for me since I have been struggling with this issue for some time. Every time I am trying to create a custom UITableViewCell and use it in a UITableView, things get mixed up. I believe it is because of the function I use to fill the cell with, in this example it's name is fillPlayerCellWithPlayer:.

I have a NSArray of PlayerContacts as my DataSource of the UITableView. My idea is to fill the cell's contents like UILabels and UIImageViews and etc with each PlayerContact properties. The usual practice is to fill these properties right in cellForRowAtIndexPath like: `tablecell.playerNameLabel.text = player.playerName` and so on. But I implement it like as follows for convenience and reasons I will tell later down below:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"PlayerCellID";
    AddPlayerObjectCell *tablecell = (AddPlayerObjectCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    NSArray * chosenPlayerArray = [self generatePlayersArrayForCategoryRow:selectedCategoryIndexRow];
    NSMutableDictionary * dict = (NSMutableDictionary *)[chosenPlayerArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    PlayerContact * player = (PlayerContact *)[dict objectForKey:@"sgfPlayer"];
    [tablecell fillPlayerCellWithPlayer:player];
    return tablecell;}
```

To explain why I don't use the common practice method, first let me share the fillPlayerCellWithPlayer function:

```
- (void) fillPlayerCellWithPlayer : (PlayerContact *) player {
    [self createGestureRegocnizer];
    myPlayer = player;  //this sets the player as the private variable of AddPlayerObjectCell class
    cellItemLabel.text = myPlayer.playerName;
    cellItemSubLabel.text = myPlayer.playerTeam;
    UIImage * img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"messi.JPG"];
    cellItemImageView.image = img; }

- (void) createGestureRegocnizer{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapFrom)];
    gesture.delegate = self;
    [self addGestureRecognizer:gesture];}

- (void) handleTapFrom{
    NSString * imageName = @"unselected_user_icon.png";
    NSString * imageNameSelected = @"selected_user_icon.png";
    if(playerSelected){
        playerSelected = NO;
        myPlayer.playerSelected = playerSelected;
        [cellItemSelectionImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];}
    else{
        playerSelected = YES;
        myPlayer.playerSelected = playerSelected;
        [cellItemSelectionImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageNameSelected]];}}
```

As You can see, when the user touches the cell, `handleTapFrom` fires and i can change the `playerSelected` property of myPlayer so i can later on use this info to filter my main array for selected players.

One of my problems is that whenever i slide my finger in the tableview of players, their selected checkmarks gets changed like crazy. I guess this is caused by my using reusable cells logic in a wrong way. If you guys can suggest me a way to this properly, i would be really happy.

And my second question is more important for me since, if you guys say its true, I want to use it as a general logic throughout my app design. Lets say i passed a NSArray named playersArray to the tableview as datasource. And the cell class changed the playersArray object that corresponds to its indexPath. In my controller class, and the classes that can access playersArray, this change is observed. This is good news for me because i don't need to make a copy of array and change its contents accordingly. Do you friends think this is a good practice for a UITableViewCell to change the contents of its UITableView's DataSource? or is UITableViewCell's only job to display a cell as needed? Should I implement this some other way? like delegation or something if I want to update the datasource?

Thank you very much in advance. I can be more clear in anyway if you guys need me to.

Aytunç İşseven

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you should avoid that the Cell is holding the data model itself and manipulating them. You also should avoid creating & adding this gesture recogniser multiple times (as that will happen if you call fillPlayerCellWithPlayer: and the cell is reused). That will increase the count of the tap recognisers and each of the will trigger the a tap. Instead you could override

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
```

on the UITableViewCell and handle your selection there. This will be triggered each time you change the selection state of the UITableViewCell. You should only change the visual appearance of the cell here as the cell should not hold the player object.

To handle the selection of the player just implement the UITableViewDelegate method (on your controller)

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and handle the manipulation of your data model there.

**The reason why is:**

The UITableViewCell is a view and following the Model-View-Controller Pattern (which Appkit is based on) the view should just represent the model without managing it. The controller (which implements the UITableViewDelegate - e.g. a UIViewController) is the connector between those two and should be the one managing the model information instead of the view as you suggested.

Comment: - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    // Configure the view for the selected state
    NSLog(@"selected PLAYER cell named: %@", cellItemLabel.text);}
when i scroll the tableview, (without pressing on any tablecells) the nslogs fire all the time. I thougth setselected only worked when pressed on the tablecell

Comment: As I mentioned you should manage the visual appearance of the cell here. And the selection of the player object on level above in your controller (e.g. UIViewController) implementing the UITableViewDelegate.

Comment: The setSelected:animated: method will be fired every time the table cell is displayed / reused to set the selection state of the cell. So do not select the data model there - instead check if your player is selected in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: and do something like cell.selected = player.isSelected - so you can make sure that even if your model is persisted & loaded you will restore the selection states in the list. cell.selected - will then trigger setSelected:animated: and you should take care of the visual appearance there

Comment: i have been trying to use your suggestions but i am getting no luck. I must be doing something wrong. First of all I understood what you told about gesrecognizer and modal-view-controller stuff perfectly. Thanks for those clarifications. The only part left is implementing the selection logic(visually and modally) using setSelected, willSelectRowAtIndexPath and cellForRowAtIndexPath(their uses?) setSelected runs all the time cell is created or reused not only when its pressed. when you said cell.selected=player.isSelected is .selected the generic variable or do i need to create mine?

Comment: cell.selected=player.isSelected will set the selected state of the cell. you can set that by yourself which will fire the setSelected:animated: of the UITableViewCell. However the table manages also a selection state of it cells e.g. if you set allowsMultipleSelection to YES. So even if you don't set the cell.selected the UITableView will call setSelected:animated: when it dequeue its cells - every time. As the cells are reused a non selected cell could be reused to display a selected cell - thats why the selection state has to be updated every time

Comment: in setSelected:animated you should call the super implementation [super setSelected:selected animated:animated]; to make cell.isSelected work properly - otherwise you have to overwrite the selected property getter and return your own internal ivar

Comment: i got it to work by your suggestions. Thanks:) if i wanted to do the selection by pressing a uibutton in the custom uitableviewcell instead of the whole cell, what would i do for updating the datasource this time? should i use delegation and protocols for my custom uitableviewcell? take care

Comment: You could set a delegate on your cell to route the tap of the button. Just set the controller as your delegate every time you are dequeue the cell. I think that is a good solution. Cheers for accepting the answer!